# How does $I(x) = \int_x^1 \sqrt{x^{-2}-1} \ dx$ evaluate to $I(x) = -\sqrt{1-x^2}+\ln\bigg[\bigg(1 + \sqrt{1^2-x^2} \bigg)/x \bigg]$?

Tags: integration, definite-integrals

I came across the following integral
$$
I(x) = \int_x^1 \sqrt{x^{-2}-1} \ dx, \quad \quad x < 1,
$$
in a paper (see equation (A.6) [here](https://arxiv.org/pdf/0708.3533.pdf)) where it is stated that this integral can be evaluated as (see equation (46) in the paper)
$$
I(x) = -\sqrt{1-x^2}+\ln\bigg[\bigg(1 + \sqrt{1^2-x^2} \bigg)/x \bigg].
$$

How is this being accomplished?

Comment: Strictly speaking, the integration variable should be different than the end-point variable. But it's a common abuse of notation and evidently one which the authors' made use of. Also, the integral is only valid for $0<x<1$ owing to the singularity at $x=0$.

Comment: I think you mean equation (46), not (41), right?

Comment: HINT...this can be evaluated directly by substituting $$\frac 1x=\cosh u$$

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Note that\begin{align}I(x)&=\int_x^1\sqrt{t^{-2}-1}\,\mathrm dt\\&=\int_x^11\times\sqrt{t^{-2}-1}\,\mathrm dt\\&=\left[t\sqrt{t^{-2}-1}\right]_{t=x}^{t=1}-\int_x^1-\frac1{t^2\sqrt{t^{-2}-1}}\,\mathrm dt\\&=-x\sqrt{x^{-2}-1}+\int_x^1\frac1{t\sqrt{1-t^2}}\,\mathrm dt\\&=-\sqrt{1-x^2}+\int_x^1\frac1{t\sqrt{1-t^2}}\,\mathrm dt.\end{align}So, what remains to be proved is that$$\int_x^1\frac1{t\sqrt{1-t^2}}\,\mathrm dt=\log\left(\frac{1+\sqrt{1-x^2}}x\right).$$These two functions are equal because both of them map $1$ into $0$ and if you differentiate any of them what you get is$$-\frac1{x\sqrt{1-x^2}}.$$

Answer (score 2):

Put $x=\cos u$, so that the integral becomes $$I(x)=\int_{\cos^{-1}x}^0 \sin u \tan u\,du$$
which can then be evaluated using the [Weierstrass half-angle substitution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tangent_half-angle_substitution) ($t=\tan\frac u2$), since the integral becomes
$$I(x) = \int_\sqrt{\frac{1-x}{1+x}}^0 \frac{8t^2}{(1-t^2)(1+t^2)^2}\,dt,$$
which can be done by partial fractions to yield the result you gave.

Answer (score 1):

Renaming the dummy variable $t$ and applying the substitution $$t = \sin \theta, \quad dt = \cos \theta \,d\theta$$ transforms the integral into
$$\int_{\arcsin x}^{\pi / 2} \frac{\cos^2 \theta \,d\theta}{\sin \theta} .$$

> Applying standard techniques for integrating rational functions in $\sin$ and $\cos$ gives that this is $$\cos \theta + \log(\csc \theta - \cot \theta) \vert_{\arcsin x}^{\pi / 2} = -[\cos \theta + \log(\csc \theta - \cot \theta)]_{\theta = \arcsin x} .$$